# How can I validate that at least 1 checkbox is checked on Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have this page in php and laravel. This is the code:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=> 'cars.store','method'=> 'POST','name'=>'cars','files' => true] ) !!}

  <div class="DivCars" id="DivCars">
    <label>*&nbsp;Please select a car</label>
    <div id="DivCarsCheck" class="DivCarsCheck">
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{$cars->name}}" value="{{$cars->id}}" name="cars_check">
      <label id="LabelCanchas" for="{{$cars->name}}">{{$cars->name}}</label>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And I have this function in javascript to validate that at least 1 checkbox must be selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function ValidateCheck(e) {      

    var form = document.cars;
    var at_least_1 = false;


    for (var i = 0; i < formulario.cars_check.length; i++) {
      if (form.cars_check[i].checked) {

         at_least_1 = true;
      }
    }

    if (!at_least_1){

       alert('You must select at least 1 option from the list');

       if (e.preventDefault) {

           e.preventDefault();

       } else {

           e.returnValue = false;
       }
    }
  }

</script>
```

How can I add this function to a **`onsubmit`** event? If I have this format to create forms:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=> 'example.store','method'=> 'POST','files' => true] ) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And how can I set a **`setCustomValidity()`** message for the checkboxes, which may appear near the checkbox list.

Comment: Create an onSubmit event and call this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the form an ID and do

```js
document.getElementById("formID").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll("[name=cars_check]");
  for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked) return true;
  }
  alert('You must select at least 1 option from the list');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```